# spark does not print log4j logs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I have added some logs using log4J but it is not getting printed when I run my application

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
val log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
log.info("testing")
```

even this is also not printing.

```
val log = Logger.getRootLogger
log.warn("Hello demo")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on how logging is done in and with Spark. (In my project we use play, so we use the play logging there. Which, I think should work with your code). But a quick search for your issue landed me on this site:

https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.log4j.Logger

Where you can see it seems that the logger has to be declared like this:
@transient lazy val logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

And perhaps you have to fix some configs?

This is my first time giving an answer so I'm sorry if it's not as helpful as it could be. But there seems to be many tutorials out there that should be able to help you.